# Configured DNS server in Fritzbox but it is not being used

Tags: networking, router, dns, opendns, fritzbox

I have a Fritzbox 7490. I set the IPv4 DNS Server to OpenDNS (208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220), but somehow these server are not used when I make requests.

How I noticed it:

There is a Domain that is being blocked by my ISP (it's s.to, but I don't know what is on there I just used it for my test scenario because I know this site is blocked). My ISP forwards one to 167.233.14.14 aka notice.cuii.info.

When use nslookup it will show me the IP from that filtered list of my provider

```bsh
~$ nslookup s.to
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
s.to    canonical name = notice.cuii.info.
Name:   notice.cuii.info
Address: 167.233.14.14
```

The DNS I use seems to work fine:

```bsh
~$ nslookup s.to 208.67.222.222
Server:     208.67.222.222
Address:    208.67.222.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   s.to
Address: 186.2.163.237

~$ nslookup s.to 208.67.220.220
Server:     208.67.220.220
Address:    208.67.220.220#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   s.to
Address: 186.2.163.237
```

In my browser I also get forwarded to the wrong IP.

I configured the DNS some month ago. There already have been one or two router restarts. The router wasn't sold by this ISP. I got it from my previous ISP (which won't forward to cuii.info), but I had to switch the ISP because I moved to another place.

Anyone an idea why I don't get the correct IP by default?

PS: There is no DNS configured on my PC settings, browser and phone. But all of them go to the wrong IP.

PPS: I'm not trying to get around the law and do bad stuff on the web. The provider just blocks these sites without a judicial order. That's what bothers me.

Comment: hi JWo, did you try this? https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/knowledge-base/publication/show/165_Configuring-different-DNS-servers-in-the-FRITZ-Box/

did you change both ipv4 and ipv6 DNS servers? does the FritzBox actually use the new DNS servers?

Comment: Hi @StefanKaerst, I only configured IPv4 settings. not v6. And yes I went into the fritzbox user interface to the DNS Settings, picked "use other DNS server" and entered the IP addresses. And no it doesn't look like the router uses the DNS server, but that is the problem. I don't know why. My device in my network use the router as DNS, as they should, but I don't get the correct IP address when I test it.

Comment: hi JWo, I especially mentioned IPv4 AND IPv6 DNS because every OS nowadays prefers IPv6 addresses - this is also true for FritzBox and DNS servers. If your FB uses global IPv6 addresses it also uses that for DNS .. if you changed only IPv4 DNS, your FB still uses the official IPv6 DNS for queries. this would explain why your internal computers get the wrong answer to s.to!
my FB 7490 webgui shows all IP addresses and all DNS servers available + the preferred DNS server in use. (which IPv6)
if you are curious you can capture WAN traffic at https://fritz.box/html/capture.html, HTH

Comment: thank you. Configuring IPv6 DNS server solved my problem. I'll write an dedicated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [StefanKaerst](https://superuser.com/users/255344/stefankaerst) I could solve my problem.

My fritzbox actually uses the IPv6 settings for DNS requests. I wasn't aware of that. Therefore I just had to set two more DNS server for IPv6.

Unfortunately I only found instructions for IPv4 settings, when I directly went to the DNS provider's website. But with a internet search I found the IPv6 settings.

The provider also suggests to check whether you are using IPv6 by going to http://www.kame.net/ . If you are seeing a swimming turtle there you can configure IPv6, too.

Answer (score 0):

Every device has DNS configured in some way - what you mean is that all your devices have automatic DNS configured. This setting comes from DHCP, presumably from the Fritzbox. On a Windows computer you can review the DNS settings with the command `ipconfig /all`. If you check this you will see that your PC is either using the Fritzbox for DNS or some DNS server. From your description your PC is not using OpenDNS.

```
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
                                    192.168.1.1
```

If you see the Fritzbox IP listed then your Fritzbox is not using OpenDNS as its upstream DNS server and you need to look at the DNS settings on the Fritzbox. If you see some other IP (maybe your ISP's DNS server) then you need to look at the DHCP settings on the Fritzbox and change them to either point at the Fritzbox or directly at OpenDNS.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I used cat /etc/resolv.conf |grep nameserver to check my current settings (I'm on Linux Mint not Windows). Currently the nameserver is 127.0.0.53. I manually changed it to my router's IP and verified that it is used with nslookup s.to But I got the same result as described above. It's good that my devices use the Fritzbox as DNS. I want all devices to use this DNS. As I said I configured the DNS IPv4 settings in my router via the user interface in the browser. I set both the regular DNS and the alternative DNS. I looks like my Fritzbox ignores this setting.

Comment: Your Linux computer uses 127.0.0.53 by design. See this Q&A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612416/why-does-etc-resolv-conf-point-at-127-0-0-53

Comment: Your original question and your comment are ambiguous and I was trying to ask about this. When you wrote "I configured the DNS IPv4 settings in my router" are you referring to the DNS targets for the router or the DNS settings given out via DHCP. They are not the same.